# How to keep the parameters' values of the Animator when it attached GameObject became disable?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, gameobject

When I disable a GameObject, I found all values inside the Animator become to default. So is any ways to keep them, or recover them after enabled the GameObject?

Or the only way can do this is manually save them?

Comment: When an Animator component or a parent GameObject is disabled, it gets reset - you'll have to write your own method for saving all the parameters in the Animator before you disable the GameObject, and applying them when you enable it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there is a way I found that can solve this problem without manually save each parameter.

Firstly, by using `Animator.parameters` ([Documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Animator-parameters.html)), we can get all parameters in the Animator. Note that it does not include the value.

`Animator.parameters` is an array of the class`AnimatorControllerParameter`, which includes a property called `AnimatorControllerParameterType type`, which is an enum:

```
public enum AnimatorControllerParameterType
{
    Float = 1,

    Int = 3,

    Bool = 4,

    Trigger = 9
}
```

So now, we can simply call the methods such as [GetBool](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Animator.GetBool.html), GetFloat in a loop to get all the variable, then use another loop to set them  by calling the method such as [SetBool](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Animator.SetBool.html) and SetFloat